# How to set dynamically QTextEdit size?

Tags: python, pyside2, qtextedit

I have `QTextEdit` where I append procedurally lines. By default `QTextEdit` breaks line if window size is less than line width and part of the line appears on the next line. I need to activate horizontal scroll bar and set text area size greater than layout size. How to achieve this kind of behaviour. I'm using `PySide2`.

Edit:

I have tried this approach but does not get real length(width) of line

```
for line in [line_one, line_two, line_three, line_four, line_five]:
    f_met = QtGui.QFontMetrics(QtGui.QFont())
    width = f_met.width(str(line))
    print width
    if width > 300:
        self.text_edit.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.FixedPixelWidth)
        self.text_edit.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(width)

    self.text_edit.append(line)
```

How to get correct length/width of the line?

Edit2:

Here is the full code. Does not matters how long is the line it always breaks line. Here is the example:

```
class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()

        self.cent_ly = MW()
        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.cent_ly.vlayout.addWidget(self.text_edit )
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cent_ly )

        line = 'BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBl'

        met = QtGui.QFontMetrics(QtGui.QFont())
        width = met.width(str(line))

        self.text_edit.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.FixedPixelWidth)
        self.text_edit.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(width)

        self.text_edit.append(line)


class MW(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MW , self).__init__()
        self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vlayout)

w = MainWidget()
w.show()
```

Comment: you may use QHBoxLayout or QScrollArea control as text_edits parent to scale text field edit when windows size caused it to break. both control has horizontal scroll enable option. see horizontalScrollBarPolicy : Qt::ScrollBarPolicy
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop

Comment: `QSrollArea ` worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Parenting `QtTextEdit` under `QScrollArea`  solved the problem.

Edit:
`QFontMetrics.width()` is obsolete. One must use `QFontMetrics.horizontalAdvance()` or

```
QFontMetrics. boundingRect().width()
```

Comment: glad to hear that!